# Map initialize and increment in one statement

Tags: php

How can I increment a map entry in one line, see comment below.:

```
$results = array();

# ...  compute $results

# I would like to replace below with one statement, is it possible?
if (!array_key_exists("cnt", $results)) {
   $results["cnt"] = 1; # first time
} else {
   $results["cnt"] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Assign it to `1` when you initialize it?

Comment: Reducing the amount of code for no good reason is usually a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $results["cnt"] = !array_key_exists("cnt", $results) ? 1 :  $results["cnt"] + 1;
```